# Is it possible to truncate the pg_largeobject table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to discard the contents of the **pg_largeobject** table and reclaim its disk space. When I try issuing this command:

```
truncate pg_largeobject
```

I get this response:

```
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_largeobject" is a system catalog
```

This is even though I am issuing the command as user **postgres** (a superuser). There is insufficient disk space to do a **VACUUM FULL** while the table contains a lot of rows. I've also tried just deleting all the rows in preparation for a **VACUUM FULL**, but this was still going after a whole day, and ended up being interrupted. I'd prefer to truncate if at all possible.

Is truncation of this table possible? It currently contains around 1 TB of images I no longer want. I've removed references to the table from all my other tables (and deleted all rows from **pg_largeobject_metadata**).

Comment: In your shoes, I would `pg_dump` the database, drop it, edit the pg_dump file as needed to get rid of any remaining images you seek to avoid, and recreate the database. I have no subtler solution for you.

Comment: Before all of that, though, I might ask the folks over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The truncate should be allowed if you enable the [`allow_system_table_mods`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-developer.html) option. I don't know if there are any consequences to modifying these tables directly, but if you've already wiped out `pg_largeobject_metadata`, I imagine you're past the point of no return...

Answer (score 4):

Turning on `allow_system_table_mods` was the answer. The truncate then took only a few minutes. Thanks to [Nick Barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104979/nick-barnes) for this suggestion and to an [old article](http://savepoint.blog.br/zerando-large-objects-numa-base-postgresql/) that confirmed this approach.